# Derive Fourier transforms from Fourier expansion. How are they related?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, laplace-transform

I am just trying to relate Fourier Series expansion to Fourier Transforms. If someone could show how one value on the middle of the [table](http://cecs.wright.edu/~jstephen/Table_of_Fourier_Transforms.jpg) is derived (from expansion) as opposed to deriving their respective equations, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say derive from expansion of (I assume) Fourier Series because that won't work for the entire table. Fourier Transforms, like Fourier Series, expands a function to it's trigonometric sum. However, Fourier Series only works with periodic functions - with Fourier Transforms, the period is assumed to tend to infinity. Formally, the Fourier Transform is denoted as

\begin{equation}
F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)e^{-ikx}\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

So, working with $f(t)=1$,

$F(k) = \int_{-a}^{a} 1e^{-ikx}\mathrm{d}x
\rightarrow F(k) = \int_{-a}^{a} e^{-ikx}\mathrm{d}x
\rightarrow \dfrac{-e^{-ikx}}{ix} \Big|_{-a}^{a} \rightarrow = i \dfrac{-e^{-iax} - e^{iax}}{x}$

where the top part of the last equation is $=-2isin(ax)$

But because the period tends to infinity, a limit needs to be taken. So, continuing,

$ \rightarrow = i \dfrac{-2isin(ax)}{x} \rightarrow = 2\dfrac{sin(ax)}{x} \rightarrow \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^{a} e^{-ikx}\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^{a} 2\dfrac{sin(ax)}{x}\mathrm{d}x = 2{\pi}{\delta}(x)$